# How to pass the contents of the file in String format as a parameter to a java method from shell script?

Tags: java, bash, shell, awk

I am calling a java method from shell script.It accepts String parameter. I am supposed to pass whole file content as a parameter.

Now from shell script I am getting the whole file Content using

`orgFileContent=$(awk '$1=$1' ORS='\\n' $orgFile)`

when I try to print this in sh..I am getting the whole content.But When I try to print this the called java method.I am just getting first two lines.

What will be the reason? How can I pass the whole file as a string?

Thanks in advance

Comment: we cannot tell, who knows what does the java method do?  or perhaps the file content has single/double quotes?  btw, I suggest you passing the file to your java, to do further processing instead of `awk ...` then java.. and your `awk '$1=$1'` is not safe either..

Comment: Thanks for ur response kent...My java method right now just prints the param it accepts, My file contents doesn't contains any quotes...I am not supposed to pass the whole file and hence I am trying to pass the contents..Can you please help on this

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a static main in class Main. You could use *xargs* command to pass the contents of the file to the executing Java program, i.e.

```
$ xargs java -classpath CLASSPATH Main < youInputFile
```

By doing so, the contents of the file will be passed over the pipe to xargs command hence you could print the file contents with a simple

```
System.out.println(args[0])
```

However, if you try to execute the command as shown below, any newline character present in your input file will mean a new passed argument, hence the same Java code would print only the first line and then ignore the rest of the file (as the 1st word is 1st arg, ...)

```
$ cat yourInputFile | xargs java -classpath CLASSPATH Main
```

Answer (score 0):

Just double quote the variable

```
java -classpath CLASSPATH Main "$orgFileContent"
```